# Removing specific value from cell of dataframe and shifting the value towards left

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with the pandas data frame. I have unwanted data in some cells. I need to clear that data from specific cells and shift the whole row towards left by one cell. I have tried couple of things but it is not working for me. Here is the example dataframe

```
     userId             movieId  ratings  extra
0       1                 500      3.5     
1       1                 600      4.5    
2       1                www.abcd      700     2.0
3       2                1100      5.0
4       2                1200      4.0
5       3                 600      4.5
6       4                 600      5.0
7       4                1900      3.5
```

Expected Outcome:

```
     userId             movieId  ratings   extra
0       1                 500      3.5
1       1                 600      4.5
2       1                 700      2.0
3       2                1100      5.0
4       2                1200      4.0
5       3                 600      4.5
6       4                 600      5.0
7       4                1900      3.5
```

I have tried the following code but it is showing the following error.

```
raw = df[f['ratings'].str.contains('www')==True] 

#Here I am trying to fix the specific cell value to empty but it shows the following error.
**AttributeError:** 'str' object has no attribute 'at'
df = df.at[raw, 'movieId'] = ' '



#code for shifting the cell value to left
df.iloc[raw,2:-1] = df.iloc[raw,2:-1].shift(-1,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shift values by mask, but is realy important match types, it means if column `movieId` is filled by strings (because at leas one string) is necessary convert it to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for avoid data lost, because different types:

```
m = df['movieId'].str.contains('www')
df['movieId'] = pd.to_numeric(df['movieId'], errors='coerce')

#if want shift only missing values rows
#m = df['movieId'].isna()   
df[m] = df[m].shift(-1, axis=1)
df['userId'] = df['userId'].ffill()
df = df.drop('extra', axis=1)
print (df)
   userId  movieId  ratings
0     1.0    500.0      3.5
1     1.0    600.0      4.5
2     1.0    700.0      2.0
3     2.0   1100.0      5.0
4     2.0   1200.0      4.0
5     3.0    600.0      4.5
6     4.0    600.0      5.0
7     4.0   1900.0      3.5
```

If omit converting to numeric get missing value:

```
m = df['movieId'].str.contains('www')
df[m] = df[m].shift(-1, axis=1)
df['userId'] = df['userId'].ffill()
df = df.drop('extra', axis=1)
print (df)
   userId movieId  ratings
0     1.0     500      3.5
1     1.0     600      4.5
2     1.0     NaN      2.0
3     2.0    1100      5.0
4     2.0    1200      4.0
5     3.0     600      4.5
6     4.0     600      5.0
7     4.0    1900      3.5
```

Comment: @jearael  I am getting this error in my original data frame when I am trying to shift```ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values```.

Comment: @Sanwal - Change `m = df['movieId'].str.contains('www')` to `m = df['movieId'].str.contains('www', na=False)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
df['movieId'] = pd.to_numeric(df['movieId'], errors='coerce')
df = df.sort_values(by = 'movieId', ascending = 'True')
```